# How to get only Message Body from a GET HTTP request?

Tags: c, http, get, http-headers

I make a HTTP GET request

```
char write = "GET /image.png HTTP/1.1\r\n";
```

[image]

And response header

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: image/png
Date: Mon, 26 Sep 2016 03:40:54 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 14021

�PNG�;oq
```

Is there a way to get only message body and avoid response headers?

Comment: What's wrong with just skippping the header by yourself (< 5 lines)

Comment: The headers are part of http. If you're  using http, you're getting headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3) the response is in the format below:

```
HTTP-message   = start-line
                  *( header-field CRLF )
                  CRLF
                  [ message-body ]
```

So search in your result for the first two CRLF's in a row. There is where the body starts..